# How to delete test posts on a Ruby-on-Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been creating my first Rails project but I would like to delete all of the test posts that I have been creating along the way.

How would I go about just removing the inputted content from the database?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe  using rake db:reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recreate your whole database, use:

```
rake db:reset
```

To delete all created Posts, use:

```
rails c
> Post.destroy_all
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I need to delete all created posts. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `db:reset` rake task:

`rake db:reset` or, if you're using bundler, `bundle exec rake db:reset`

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
     in `rails console`

```
1) Post.destroy_all 
2) ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE posts RESTART IDENTITY")
```

in command

`rake db:reset`